# How to design schedule service interface

Tags: user-expectation, web-app

I am trying to create an understandable and clear UX design for a schedule designer web app.

Imagine we have **categories** of **followers** and marketing **emails** to send. Also we have a schedule: each **day** we are going to send some pool of emails of some category.

Here is the data model:
[image]

Sometimes we need to move an email of some category to another day on the schedule, so
***emails on a day ≠ emails of a Followers category***.

My current design:
[image]

The primary call to action is a `Generate schedule` button. We suggest that the user arrange categories by day; the user then generates the schedule. If the user needs to move an email to another day, it has to be done on another screen.

Question: If the user moves an email to another day, they have to re-generate the schedule. All edits to the previous version will be lost. What is a more elegant way to help the user create a "ready to use" schedule on the fly?

Comment: Hi igolka97, what is the problem with your current interface?

Comment: @Nash thanks for your question, updated my answer

Comment: Hi, quick question - is the flow diagram above meant to be read right-to-left?

Comment: @izquierdo may be. Does it matter? It’s just a data model, it could be read from any place, I think. 

Ps. thanks for your job under editing my question. Hope it going to become my question more clear. In fact I’m just looking for right decision.

Comment: The flow direction will help us understand which items are dependent on other items.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined categories for followers, which probably allows you to determine which types of emails to send to them. However, I don't see any reference to email categories in the data model as a property.

Also, I think if you define the concept of a schedule, perhaps in terms of an email category with some rules about the frequency or amount of emails to send, and who they are sent to, then you might be able to enable such features.

The Generate Schedule call-to-action is essentially a 'magic button' that populates fields according to the rules. There isn't enough detail in the data model to suggest how those rules can be created, so you'll have to provide those details first.